# Avoid extracting a word with a specific term

Tags: regex, regex-group

My plan is to extract group of words from a string with regex. However, I have sometimes the word `NOT` in front of a word which should be extracted. Not sure how to deal with that issue.

Test string:

```
tag=os index=linux index=windows NOT index=mac tag=db index="a_something-else" NOT   index=solaris
```

Current (failing) regex expression:

```
index=(\")?(?<my_indexes>\w+(-)?(\w+)?)(\")?
```

This regex expression is extracting all `index=zyx` words. But the case with the `NOT` e.g. `NOT index=mac` or `NOT   index=solaris` should be avoided. E.g. the results should be like:

```
index=linux
index=windows
index="a_something-else"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What environment are you running your regex from? Using a variable-length negative lookbehind would make solving your problem trivial, but those aren't implemented in most regex flavours

Comment: @Aaron it will be Splunk. It uses PCRE. Reference: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/SearchReference/Rex

Comment: Then it should allow variable width lookbehind and simply prefixing your regex with `(?<!NOT\s+)` should do the trick, it checks that what it matches isn't preceded by "NOT" followed by any number of space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you meantion that it is PCRE, one option is to use a SKIP FAIL pattern, and use a capturing group with a backreference to pair up the matching double quote.

Then you can make the double quote optional inside the capturing group and refer to it using `\1` and `\2`

note that you don't have to escape the double quote by itself.

```
\bNOT\h+index=("?)\w+(?:-\w+)*\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|index=("?)\w+(?:-\w+)*\2
```

**Explanation**

- `\bNOT\h+` Match NOT and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `index=("?)` Match `index=` And capture an optional `"` in **group 1**
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*\1` Match 1+ word chars, optionally repeated by `-` and 1+ word chars. Then a backreference to what is captured in group 1
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` Skip the match
- `index=("?)` Match `index=` And capture an optional `"` in **group 2**
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*\2` The same as the previous pattern above, now with a backreference to group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MVTYp/1)

If you don't want the double quotes around `a_something-else` and only want the value after the `=`,  you could use another capturing group, or use the named capturing group `my_indexes`

```
\bNOT\h+index=("?)\w+(?:-\w+)*\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|index=("?)(?<my_indexes>\w+(?:-\w+)*)\2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJTkj6/1)